# Jquery UI Dialog blocks entering text in textbox

Tags: jquery

I have textbox and button in my page. After entering the text and clicking the button the modal dialog box opens. When the dialog box is opened at that time i unable to enter text in textbox which is outside of dialog box. so anyone please help me.

Comment: Can you put some code?

Comment: Modal dialog overlaps the content of the html page as it has the fixed/absolute position and greater `z-index` than any other element on the page. So will need to customize modal box styling to meet your requirements.

Comment: Well that's the point of a *modal* dialog box, don't use `modal: true`

Comment: Thanks Alex , I removed modal:true and it is works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isssue can be resolved by removing modal:true from dialog code